# Select first child <p> in Deliverance

Tags: plone, plone-3.x, deliverance

Given the following content:

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="brian">
    <p>Hello my name is Alex</p>
    <p>My surname is Thomas</p>
    <p>My middle name is James</p>
    <p>true story...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And with the following in my theme:

```
<div id="dave" />
```

How so I replace `#dave` with the first paragraph? I've tried:

- `<replace content="//div[@class='content']/p" theme="div#dave" />`
- `<replace content="//div[@class='content']/p[1]" theme="div#dave" />`
- `<replace content="children://div[@class='content']/p" theme="meta#description" />`

Neither worked... Please note that `.content` is buried fairly deep and can change position, so using its XPath is not an option. By xPath I mean `/div/div/p[1]` etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
<replace css:content=".content p:first-child" css:theme="#dave" />
```

Could be the solution ;)
Vito

Comment: I made a mistake, take a look now to my solution

Comment: Note that the questionner is using Deliverance, not plone.app.theming/Diazo so the syntax is slightly different. css:content and css:theme is a Diazo thing not a Deliverance thing.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure xslt solution try this:

```
<replace content="//div[@class='content']/p[1]" theme="div#dave" />
```

**edit**:

i meant:

```
 <replace content="//div[@class='content']//p[1]" css:theme="div#dave" />
```

or

```
<replace content="//div[@class='content']/div/p[1]" css:theme="div#dave" />
```

Comment: errrmmm guess you didnt fully read the question. I've tried this option.

Comment: grrr that still didn't work. unfortunately i can not use `<replace content="//div[@class='content']/div/p[1]" theme="div#dave" />` as it may not always be nested in the second `<div>`. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

The `:first-child` CSS selector should work -- so it would be something like

`<replace content="p:first-child" theme="#dave" />`